# Java boolean not behaving with breakpoints in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Basically, this peice of code seems to behaving differently when I move the breakpoints

```
    int checker = something.length(); /* something is the value of an edittext */

    boolean badInput = false;

    if(checker == 0)
    {
        badInput = true;
    }

    if(checker > 12)
    {
        badInput = true;
    }

*1  if(badInput = false)
    {
*2      /* A lot of 
               code to do 
               if the 
               input is GOOD */
    }
    else
    {
            /* Alert that the input is BAD */
    }
```

When I enter a **2 digit number** into the edittext with **the first breakpoint (1)**, `badInput` gives false, as it should.

**Here is the problem:** when I do **exactly the same** with only **the second breakpoint (2)**, the code goes onto the `else` statement, and alerts, even though the input is exactly the same.

Anybody know why this might be?

Comment: Dunno if it's related to your problem with the breakpoint, but `if (badInput = false)` should probably be `if (badInput == false)`, or even better, `if (!badInput)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
if(badInput = false)
```

Should be:

```
if(badInput == false)
```

Or preferrably:

```
if (!badInput)
```

The first is performing an *assignment*, not a *comparison*. The overall result of the expression `badInput = false` is also the value assigned (false) so it will never enter the body of that `if`.

It's not really clear what you mean by entering data "with" a breakpoint, but fundamentally the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should have:

```
if(!badInput)
```

or

```
if(badInput==false)
```

(the first one is better)

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo error,

```
if(badInput = false)
```

should be

```
if(badInput == false)
```

you want a compare not assign.

Answer (score 1):

What you check boolean variable with == operator ?!!
You have to check as following :

```
if(!badInput) //for false value
    or 
if(badInput)  //for true value
```